# Wireshark packets getting bundled

Tags: wireshark, trace

[image]

While taking wireshark ISUP trace, the messages are getting bundle (shown in below picture), it is same even i open it with other versions of Wireshark.

How can I split these packets ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple messages contained within a single packet, so Wireshark is just displaying all the messages the packet contains.  This can happen any time you have a streaming transport protocol because packet boundaries do not necessarily correspond to message boundaries.  This is the normal and expected behavior of Wireshark.

In any case, you can't simply split each message to appear as a separate packet, at least not in any way I know of, but there might be other tools besides Wireshark that would be better suited for analyzing this type of traffic, I don't know.  A quick google search would seem to indicate that others exist, for example: [SIGTRAN Protocol Analyzer](http://www.gl.com/ss7.html).